Sum to zero contrast that makes it easy to express equal uncertainty about each factor level
How do I need to set-up a sum-to-zero contrast so that it is easy to express equal uncertainty about each factor level? E.g. when I go with the default offered by R such as:
mydf <- data.frame(y=c(-0.1, 0.1, 0.9,1.1, 1.9,2.1, 2.9,3.1, 3.9,4.1), 
                   var = factor(rep(seq(0, 4, 1), each=2)))

contrasts(mydf$var) <- contr.sum

This produces
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
0    1    0    0    0
1    0    1    0    0
2    0    0    1    0
3    0    0    0    1
4   -1   -1   -1   -1

which seems to suggest that the contrasts contribute to different factor levels with different multiplicative constants (which is no problem at all, when I'm doing maximum likelihood estimation, as everything just gets scaled appropriately).
However, let's say I want to express equal uncertainty about each category. If I set the same prior for all terms, that doesn't seem to happen:
library(brms)
library(tidybayes)
    
prior_samples <- brm(formula = y ~ var, 
                     data=mydf,
                     family = gaussian(), 
                     prior = prior(class=Intercept, normal(0, 1)) + 
                       prior(class=b, normal(0, 1)) +
                       prior(class=sigma, lognormal(-10, 0.1)), 
                     sample_prior = "only", 
                     iter = 110000, 
                     warmup=1000)

data.frame(var = factor(seq(0, 4, 1))) |>
  add_predicted_rvars(object = prior_samples, ndraws = NULL)

produces
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  var       .prediction
  <fct>      <rvar[1d]>
1 0       0.00186 ± 1.4
2 1       0.00085 ± 1.4
3 2      -0.00134 ± 1.4
4 3       0.00079 ± 1.4
5 4       0.00158 ± 2.2

As you can see the prior uncertainty for the 5th factor level is higher than for the others. Maybe I could find some complicated way to specify my prior that deals with this, but it seems like it would be easier to change my contrasts somehow to avoid this (but I struggle to figure out how to do this).
EDIT: I noticed that $1.4 \approx \sqrt(2)$ and $2.2 \approx \sqrt(5)$, which seems to correspond to having 2 and 5 terms with variance 1 added up for the respective contrasts. My first thought was to add a denominator in the last row of the contrast (e.g. making it -1/5 or -1/sqrt(5). However, this doesn't seem to do the right thing, either, the problem seems to be that there's really a fifth column to the contrast (corresponding to the intercept) and I seem to be unable to set a "weight" on the intercept in the same way. I can add a 5th column, but this last column gets ignored by R (e.g. the output of lm(data=mydf, formula=y ~ var) remains completely unchanged no matter what entry I put in the last row of the fifth column). Am I missing something?

Indeed, contrasts that transform i.i.d. normal priors on $N - 1$ coefficients into $N$ effects with identical marginal distributions do exist.
One such construction is shown in Section 7.2. of Rouder et al. 2011.
A similar (maybe even isomorphic, didn't check) construction is described in Stan User's guide (with code).
matrix[K, K] A = diag_matrix(rep_vector(1, K));
matrix[K, K - 1] A_qr;
for (i in 1:K - 1) A[K, i] = -1;
A[K, K] = 0;
A_qr = qr_Q(A)[ , 1:(K - 1)];

now A_qr holds your contrasts (to keep the prior scale you further need to multiply by 1/sqrt(1 - 1/K).
Some discussion about this approach and further references can be found at https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/test-soft-vs-hard-sum-to-zero-constrain-choosing-the-right-prior-for-soft-constrain/3884/19
